# Coq unification on record params

Tags: coq

I have defined topology space like this,

```
Require Export Ensembles.
Arguments Full_set {U}.
Arguments Empty_set {U}.
Arguments In {U}.
Arguments Intersection {U}.
Arguments Union {U}.
Arguments Complement {U}.

Definition Family A := Ensemble (Ensemble A).
Inductive FamilyUnion {T : Type} (F: Family T) : Ensemble T :=
  | family_union_intro: forall (S:Ensemble T) (x:T),
      In F S -> In S x -> In (FamilyUnion F) x.

Inductive FamilyIntersection {T: Type} (F: Family T) : Ensemble T :=
  | family_intersect_intro : forall x, (forall (S:Ensemble T), (In F S) -> (In S x)) -> (In (FamilyIntersection F) x).

Record Topology : Type := mkTopology
{

          Point: Type;
          Open: Ensemble (Ensemble Point) ;
          EmptyOpen: (In Open Empty_set) ;
          FullOpen: (In Open Full_set) ;
          IntersectionOpen: forall x y,  (In Open x) -> (In Open y) -> (In Open (Intersection x y)) ;
          UnionOpen: forall F: (Family Point), (forall x: (Ensemble Point), (In F x) -> (In Open x)) -> In Open (FamilyUnion F)
}.


Definition Closed (T: Topology) := forall C: (Ensemble (Point T)),  In (Open T) (Complement C).
```

But when I try to define,

```
Theorem TopologyViaClosedSet {P: Type} (closed: Ensemble (Ensemble P)) 
    (emptyClosed: (In closed Empty_set)) 
    (fullClosed: (In closed Full_set)) 
    (unionClosed: (forall x y,  (In closed x) -> (In closed y) -> (In closed (Union x y)))) 
    (intersectionClosed: (forall F:(Family P), (forall x: (Ensemble P), (In F x) -> (In closed x)) -> (In closed (FamilyIntersection F)))) : 
    exists t: Topology,  forall x,  (In (Open t) x) <-> (In closed x)
```

It throws unification error. Which I understand why it cant be done, But Is it possible for me to hint Coq that, the point field inside the `t` is `P` somehow (`(Point t) = P`)?

Comment: There are a few missing bits to make this example compilable so we can reproduce, for example: what options did you set to hide the implicit argument of `In` (or are you using a different `Ensemble`?), and what is `Family`?

Comment: I will update it with the entire listing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that in `exists t : Topology, forall x : P, ...` we would like `Point t` to be judgementally equal to `P`, which is bound farther up. I don't think that is possible, so I would propose as alternatives (that you may have already considered):

- Index the topology by its point field, redefining `Topology` as `Topology (Point : Type)`
- Relate point fields via bijections: `exists (t : Topology) (f : P <-> Point Topology), forall x : P, In (Open t) (f x) <-> In closed x`

Comment: I tried a middle ground by indexing the `Topology` with `Point` as implicit parameter. But the definition of Closed started throwing unification errors on `In (Open T) ...` Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this compiles https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/2fd8268585bb9a5e3f249c6eaf2adac1

Comment: Okay, parameterizing Closed with `P` makes it work. Thanks a lot